# best way to convert DataFrame to Matrix in RCpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I have an RCpp code, where in a part of code I am trying to convert a DataFrame to a Matrix. The DataFrame only has numbers (no strings or dates).

The following code works:

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix testDFtoNM1(DataFrame x) {
  int nRows=x.nrows();  
  NumericMatrix y(nRows,x.size());
  for (int i=0; i<x.size();i++) {
    y(_,i)=NumericVector(x[i]);
  }  
  return y;
}
```

I was wondering if there is alternative way (i.e. equivalent of `as.matrix` in R) in RCpp to do the same, something similar to the following code below (which does NOT work):

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix testDFtoNM(DataFrame x) {
  NumericMatrix y(x);  
  return y;
}
```

*** EDIT ***

Thanks for the answers. As Dirk suggested, the C++ code is around 24x faster than either of the two answers and `Function` version is 2% faster than the `internal::convert_using_rfunction` version.

I was originally looking for an answer within RCpp without calling R. Should have made that clear when I posted my question.

Comment: I'd go with the solution you have in your question. We may need a better way to get `n` as well as `k` from the data.frame (ie as length of names vector). Otherwise it is a good solution in my mind which I like as well as some of the suggested answers.

Comment: And I was of course wrong about n and k retrievers as we do have `.size()`, I was mainly thinking of functions with similar names to those for matrices. May add that at some point...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Similar to Gabor's version, you can do something like this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp ;

//[[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix testDFtoNM(DataFrame x) {
  NumericMatrix y = internal::convert_using_rfunction(x, "as.matrix");  
  return y;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you don't mind calling back to R it can be done compactly like this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix DF2mat(DataFrame x) {
    Function asMatrix("as.matrix");
    return asMatrix(x);
}
```

**UPDATE** Incorporated Romain's comment.

Comment: I would not trust to `static` a `Function` though.

Comment: Calling to R has cost. I'd do it in C++.

Comment: @Dirk, Yes, if this were time critical but its not necessarily true that every part of a C++ program must be fast.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck just get the function at runtime. So have the `Function asMatrix("as.matrix")` inside `DF2mat`.